# I'm unable to view my pages made in WordPress rather than home page how do I solve it?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I have connected the domain with my wordpress website and the homepage the main page is working but other pages are showing errors as show in image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB1zw.png)

I have tried to deactivated all plugins and changed theme but it won't work and same problem occur with, when i make new page this my website link https://selfcrypto.io/terms-and-conditions/

Comment: That's an old Worpress bug. Just go the the *Permalinks* page in the backend once (no changes required), and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the wrong permalink structure. In admin, select Settings -> Permalinks -> Permalink structure -> Post name and save changes.

Also, you may have the wrong Nginx config. [Here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/) is the proper one.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: I have added the second suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace default .htaccess and then then resave permalink structure once.

Comment: He is on Nginx.